# java.net.UnknownHostException Cannot create socket. Java

Tags: java, sockets, http

I read some manuals and tried to create Socket, how it looks like in examples.

```
Socket socket = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName("http://google.com"), 80);
```

or

```
Socket socket = new Socket("http://google.com", 80);
```

In any case, I get the UnknownHostException:

```
java.net.UnknownHostException: http://google.com: Name or service not known
```

How will it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `www.google.com` instead.  I just tried telnet `http://google.com` and it doesn't connect.  telnet `www.google.com 80` does connect however.

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class socket_client
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
    {
        Socket s = new Socket();
    String host = "www.google.com";

        try
        {
        s.connect(new InetSocketAddress(host , 80));
        }

        //Host not found
        catch (UnknownHostException e) 
        {
            System.err.println("Don't know about host : " + host);
            System.exit(1);
        }

        System.out.println("Connected");
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add a bit of explanation here. Just dropping code is not a good way of answering questions.